# How do I use a regex to find a duplicated string on the left and the right of an equals sign

Tags: regex

I have a file with some translation and some missing translations where the english key equals the translation.

```
...
/* comment1 */
"An unexpected error occurred." = "Ein unerwarteter Fehler ist aufgetreten.";

/* comment2 */
"Enter it here..." = "Enter it here...";
...
```

Is it possible to:

1. Find all occurrences of `"X" = "X";`?
2. Bonus: For all occurrences delete the line, the comment line above and newline above that?

Comment: It is possible, which language do you want to use the regex with?

Comment: @swenzel - Its a one off task on a large file - I was hoping to do it in a text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use backreferences here, something along the lines of:

```
/"(.+)"\s*=\s*"\1"/
   ^           ^
   |           |
   |           backreference to first string
   |
  capture group for first string
```

Note that the syntax for backreferences varies between languages, the above one works for your case in Ruby, e.g.

```
❯ irb
2.2.2 :001 > r = /"(.+)"\s*=\s*"\1"/
 => /"(.+)"\s*=\s*"\1"/
2.2.2 :002 > r.match('"foo" = "foo"')
 => #<MatchData "\"foo\" = \"foo\"" 1:"foo">
2.2.2 :003 > r.match('"foo" = "bar"')
 => nil
```

In response to your comment about wanting to do it in a text editor, remove the leading/trailing slashes and the above regex should work fine in Sublime Text... YMMV in other editors.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the occurences by matching each line with the following pattern: `"(.*?)"\s*=\s*"\1"`, if you got a match you can delete the line.

### Java working example

```
public class StackOverflow32507709 {
    public static String pattern;

    static {
        pattern = "\"(.*?)\"\\s*=\\s*\"\\1\"";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] text = {
            "/* comment1 */",
            "\r\n",
            "\"An unexpected error occurred\" = \"German translation...\";\r\n",
            "\r\n",
            "\"Enter it here\" = \"Enter it here\";\r\n"
        };

        List<String> filteredTranslations = new ArrayList<String>();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        for (String line : text) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

            if (!m.find()) {
                filteredTranslations.add(line);
            }

            m.reset();
        }

        for (String filteredTranslation : filteredTranslations) {
            System.out.println(filteredTranslation);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Bonus question:

```
(\R\R)?+/\*[^*]*(?:\*+(?!/)[^*]*)*\*/\R("[^"]*") = \2;(?(1)|\R{0,2})
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZ9lO2/1)

(works with notepad++, remove the newline above, except for the first item.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a backreference, like this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

I can't give you a full answer because you haven't said which programming language you are using, but I'm sure you can figure it out from there.